# Correctly using promises with node-mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

I have been trying to do a simple query and return the results with `node-mysql` however I had several problems. Originally I wrote it where there was no promise, but if I tried to access user after just doing a query if returned undefined

The solution I came up with is the following, is this a good way of doing it? I need to wait until the results come back so I can then send a signal to the frontend to say the player is loaded and can play. Do I need to create a new promise for each query? I have a few tables I need to get data from (That can't be done with joins)

````
class Player {
    constructor(user_id, socket, connection) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.connection = connection;

        this.loadUser(user_id)
            .then(() => {
                console.log("loaded user", this.user);
            });
    }

    async loadUser(user_id) {
        let _self = this;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            _self.connection.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ${user_id}`, (err, res) => {
                this.user = res[0];
                resolve()
            });
        })
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Is `node-mysql` that the package [@node-mysql/mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@node-mysql/mysql)?

Comment: No it's https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

Comment: Async constructors would solve your problem easily if JavaScript supported them. 
 There's a proposal here: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-init

Answer (score 1):

Remove the async method call from the constructor, and make the async method return the instance (`this`):

```
class Player {
  constructor(user_id, socket, connection) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.connection = connection;
  }

  async loadUser() {
    let _self = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      _self.connection.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ${this.user_id}`, (err, res) => {
        this.user = res[0];
        resolve(this)
      });
    })
  }
}
```

Then you can instantiate a `new Player` and wait for it to load the necessary data from the database, all in one line, like this:

```
const player = await new Player(user_id, socket, connection).loadUser();
```

Or like this:

```
new Player(user_id, socket, connection).loadUser().then(player => {

});
```